# How to distribute app workload between workspaces (containers) on cloud9.io?

Tags: python, docker, c9.io

How can I implement this strategy on c9?

my_python_script.py is on https://ide.c9.io/user/my_workspace

my_python_script.py sends some text to https://ide.c9.io/user/my_other_workspace

my_python_script.py launches process_text.sh on https://ide.c9.io/user/my_other_workspace

my_python_script.py retrieves processed text from https://ide.c9.io/user/my_other_workspace

I need two workspaces because resource limitations prevent me from doing this on one workspace

Both workspaces contain (different) memory hogging neo4j databases

One db processes text for NLP. The other db stores stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that cloud9.io don't offer a direct way to do this. Each workspace is completely separate from others, since these exist in different Docker containers. I could look into creating a listener on ports 8080-8082 on the other workspace that can fire off the bash script when hit. Alternately, I could use an SSH workspace as that will give me all the resources I need.